# Getting error on TextFieldEditingController

Tags: flutter, texteditingcontroller

I want to add textfield that has its own unique index. So I declared a list of TextFieldEditingController and call it in the Wrap(). `controllers.add(TextEditingController()),`. But I am getting this error while calling it. I am getting this error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.`.

```
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];

 Wrap(
                      children: retrieveData.map((order) {
                    return Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Card(
                              child:
                                  SvgPicture.asset('assets/toiletpaper.svg')),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                CustomText(
                                    text: order.commodityName.toString()),
                                CustomText(text: '60 rolls per pack'),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: screenHeight(context) / 40,
                                ),
                                controllers.add(TextEditingController()), // this is the error
                                Flexible(
                                  child: TextFormValidator(
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      contentPadding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                                      outlineInputBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      controller: description,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList()),
```

Answer (score 0):

The line causing the error is just an expression: `controllers.add(...)` returns `void`. You placed that line inside of the `children: [...]` list, which has the type `List<Widget>`.

That's why this doesn't work:

```
children: [CustomText(...), CustomText(...), controllers.add(...), Flexible(...)]
            ^ Widget         ^ Widget             ^ void             ^ Widget
```

I don't understand entirely what you are trying to achieve, that's why I can't give you a working solution, but maybe this will work:

```
Wrap(
   children: retrieveData.map((order) {
       controllers.add(TextEditingController())   // move the line here
       return Row(
             children: [
                 ...
             ]
       );
    }).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `children` property of the `Column` widget is just a `List<Widget>`, so it accepts only the actual flutter widget to be set inside of it, in your code, by doing the:

```
 SizedBox(
   height: screenHeight(context) / 40,
    ),
 controllers.add(TextEditingController()),
 //...
```

you're trying just to put another type than what is accepted from the `children` property, the `add()` method do just add elements to a `List` which is the `controllers` list and doesn't really return a `Widget`, it has a type of `void`, so the error is thrown.

you will need to take it and put it in a scope that accepts calling method (`add()`), like `build()` function scope, a lifecycle method such `initState()`, or even wrapping a widget with a `Builder` widget then call it inside the `builder` property.. :

```
Widget build() {
 controllers.add(TextEditingController()),

// Your widget here
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get each textfield have its own unique controller. now each textfield has the same controller. [This is my current textfield with the same controller](https://imgur.com/d3P5af9)  I am not sure how to assigned the textfield with their own controller